# JMeter - Passing the number of threads to multiple thread groups

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a file where I specify the number of threads for each Thread Group.
My goal is to run **concurrently** all Thread Groups with the number of threads read from the file.

My current algorithm: I have the first Thread Group in the Test Plan called Setup.
I read the data file to the local variables.
With the BeanShell Sampler, I convert those variables into the properties variables.
In each Thread Group, the number of threads is defined via the properties variable.

If I run the Thread Groups **consecutively**, there are no problems.
But I need to run them **in parallel**. I imagine that the Thread Group can try to run before the Setup group finishes reading the number of threads for that group. Then that group will never run.

I appreciate any thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My current algorithm: I have the first Thread Group in the Test Plan
>   called Setup. I read the data file to the local variables. With the
>   BeanShell Sampler, I convert those variables into the properties
>   variables. In each Thread Group, the number of threads is defined via
>   the properties variable.

You could use [Property File Reader](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/). This will get loaded before any thread group starts. So you would not face any issue.

If you do not like Property File Reader, whatever you do - reading the data file and converting them into properties - do that in `setUp Thread Group`.

[image]

It will get executed before any thread group starts

Comment: I like you Property File Manager, but I need to read data from the JSON file, not key/value pairs.  Is the setUp group executed once before any other groups even I want to run the test groups in parallel?

Comment: "setUp group executed once before any other groups even I want to run the test groups in parallel" - Yes. This will get executed first.

Comment: Thank you, Vinoth.

Comment: @Vladimir, glad that it helped

Comment: @vins but there is no correlation between the groups

Answer (score 4):

You can define the number of threads via JMeter properties in at least 2 more ways:

1. In *user.properties* file (the file is located in JMeter's "bin" folder, JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up)

   ```
   threads=100
   ```
2. Or you can do the same via `-J` command-line argument, i.e. start JMeter as:

   ```
   jmeter -Jthreads=100 -n -t ....
   ```

In your Thread Groups you can refer the property via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
 ${__P(threads)}
```

It is also possible to have "default" value which will be used in case of "threads" property will not be defined:

```
${__P(threads,50)}
```

References:

- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Dmitri, I need to read the number of threads for each Thread Group from one JSON file. And I need to run all the test groups in parallel. If I have one dedicated Thread Group (let's call it Config) in the beginning of the Test Plan that reads the JSON file and converts them to the properties variables, I guess it can be a situation when the test Thread Group is ready to run, but the Config group did not finish reading the number of threads for that group. It means the group will never run since the number of threads are not defined yet.

Comment: Use [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) with 1 user and 1 loop to read the JSON. You can use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler using `file` protocol and [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to read the values, check out [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-extract-data-files-jmeter) for details on the approach

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri.